# Webservice Call HTTPS

Tags: javascript, web-services

I am trying to make an https call to a web-service using XMLHttpRequest object in javascript. i successfully made a regular http call but having trouble getting the https working. The https call requires an ssl cert so any ideas how to attach the cert for this call ?

```
    url2="https://myServer/axis2/webService/...";        
envelope2 =
        '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">' +
           '<soap:Header/>' +
           '<soap:Body>' +
                        .....
           '</soap:Body>' +
        '</soap:Envelope>';
```

.. then

```
 xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action=\"urn:getProjectInfo\"");
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", len);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "urn:getProjectInfo");
```

the problem is how to handle the ssl keystore to make the call ...
thanks for any help/insight

Comment: You can not make a call to a https resource from a http page. The [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) forbids it. Maybe that is your problem?

Comment: could be.. I'm just not able to call Methods and to get data from the Webservice, its SSL protected.. But with Objective C - (for Iphone it worked with Delegates etc)..

Answer (score 1):

You don't attach a cert for the call. You have to install the SSL cert on the server this is running on. If the SSL cert is installed, then the call will work simply by making it HTTPS.

Like Pekka referred to, you will run into a same-origin-policy issue if the page you are making the request from is not the exact same domain: in this case "https://myserver/" (capitalization is not important).

Comment: can u just tell me, how to do this: "then the call will work simply by making it HTTPS"..?

Comment: Yeah, instead of making a call to `http://myServer/....` It would be `https://myServer/.....`. You're already doing this though so there's no real code change.